# How to create faces that have proper material assignment

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, unity

I'm currently working on project and am very new to Blender. Let me explain my situation here so you aren't confused. I have a map that I imported into blender from the Source Engine, specifically from HL2DM.

In the game it uses a Skybox that blocks the view of imperfections such as missing faces.

[image]

In the game I'm using my imported map in I don't have the ability to do such a thing since it uses the Unity engine.

[image]

I want to create faces for the areas that are missing them and apply the proper materials for them to look like part of the map. The issue I'm running into is visible in the second image on the roof of the buildings to the left.

Currently it has no material applied to it but when I do apply a material it causes other materials on the map to use the wrong ones.

I'm wondering how I fix this if I have to UV unwrap or UV map them to the proper areas or what. I would also LOVE to know how to edit multiple materials properties similar to unity.

Comment: Please use paragraphs walls of text are unfriendly to read. Looks like you have to unwrap your newly created faces.

Comment: Thanks and sorry am new to this site. @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: I know HL2 maps and Blender and I think you should have gotten the missing faces the same way you got the other faces. Where are you exporting the geometry, looks like compiled map? Is there occlusion culling that causes you to miss faces? Applying a material (what do you mean by that?) does not affect other faces than the ones you're editing. 
And I'm pretty sure you can create a material that clears to skyboxlike in HL2 in Unity as well.